# Ajax POST desde Area en .NET MVC devuelve 403 Acceso Denegado

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

Estoy realizando una petición POST utilizando Ajax que **funciona correctamente en mi Localhost** pero la misma devuelve el error **403 Forbidden - Acceso Denegado en el Servidor**.
Me contacté con los Administradores del Server y después de 12 largos días me dijeron que no encuentran un error o falta de permisos.

[image: 403 Forbidden]

Extrañamente hago OTRA petición (NO desde un Área) y funciona correctamente. Dejo ambas peticiones:
(También probé hacer la petición que funciona desde el Área y funciona)

**Funcional:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("GetNombre","Usuarios", new { Area = "" })",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (foo) {
            $(".foo-class").html('Hola, ' + foo.nombre + '!');
        }
    });
});
```

**NO Funcional (Devuelve 403):**

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            //Preparacion y llenado de Lista
            var lstContacto_Clientes = [];

            $("div[id*='contacto-']").each(function () {
            ......
            });

            //Datos Cliente
            var Cliente = {
            ......
            }

            $.post({
                url: "@Url.Action("Crear", "Clientes")",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    oClienteView: Cliente,
                    lstContactoClientes: lstContacto_Clientes
                },
                success: function (result) {
                .....
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log('JSON Error');
                    console.log(e);
                }
            });

        });
```

Este es el Routing del Area(Por eso no aclaro el Área en el Url.Action de arriba):

```
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_Rout",
        "Admin/AdminPanel/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "AdminPanel", action = "Index",  id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "AdminPanel", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Subidivsion de Carpetas:

[image: Subdivison Carpetas]

Por último, el Controlador Clientes está afectado por los siguientes Filtros de Autorización:

```
public class AutorizacionRolesAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly string[] allowedroles;
    public AutorizacionRolesAttribute(params string[] roles)
    {
        //De AutorizacionRoles(Roles="") recibe los valores de -Roles=""- y los guarda en un array de strings
        this.allowedroles = roles;
    }
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool authorize = false;
        //Recibe el ID del Usuario por la sesion
        int? userId = (int?)httpContext.Session["SessionId"];
        var token = httpContext.Session["token"];

        //Chequea solamente si recibe UNICAMENTE el param "Token", ningun otro
        //asi se chequea en la accion "Crear" si está habilitado
        if (allowedroles[0] == "Token") 
        {
            //Si NO esta vacio, devuevle TRUE
            if(token != null)
            return true;
        }
        //Chequea si userId es valido
        if (userId > 0 && userId != null)
            using (var db = new PBIEntities())
            {
                //Recibe el Rol del Usuario
                var userRole = (from u in db.Usuarios
                                join r in db.Roles on u.rol equals r.ID_Rol
                                where u.id_usuario == userId
                                select new
                                {
                                    r.Rol
                                }).FirstOrDefault();

                //Chequea que el Rol del Usuario esté habilitado recorriendo allowedroles
                foreach (var role in allowedroles)
                {
                    if (role == userRole.Rol) return true;
                }
            }


        return authorize;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
           new RouteValueDictionary
           {
                { "controller", "Home" },
                { "action", "Index" },
               { "Area", "" }
           });
    }
}
```

```
    public class AutorizacionSesion : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var sessionId = HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionId"];
    
            var token = HttpContext.Current.Session["token"];
    
            //Si NO hay sesion
            if(sessionId == null)
            {
                //Si hay Token
                if (token != null)
                {
                    //Si el Controller es distinto de Usuarios
                    if (filterContext.Controller is UsuariosController == false)
                    {
                        //Devolver al Login
                        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Usuarios/Login");
                    }
                } else { 
                    //Si el Controlador es Distinto de Usuarios
                    if (filterContext.Controller is UsuariosController == false)
                    {
                        //Devolver al login
                        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Usuarios/Login");
                    }
                }
            } 
    
    
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

**Edit:** (En el formulario estoy utilizando **@Html.AntiForgeryToken()**)

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Crear(Clientes oClienteView,List<Contacto_Clientes> lstContactoClientes)
        {
            ViewBag.peticion = false;
            ViewBag.error = false;
            JSONRespuesta JSONresp = new JSONRespuesta();

            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    using (FOOEntities db = new FOOEntities())
                    {
                        using (DbContextTransaction transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
                        {
                            try
                            {
                             .....
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                transaction.Rollback();
                                JSONresp.error = true;
                                JSONresp.data = e.Message;
                                return Json(JSONresp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }

                JSONresp.error = false;
                JSONresp.op = "validacion";
                JSONresp.data = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(e => e.Errors);

                return Json(JSONresp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                JSONresp.error = true;
                JSONresp.data = e.Message;

                return Json(JSONresp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Comment: revisaste el tema de Cross-Domain?

Comment: ¿En *Localhost* funciona correctamente la ruta que devuelve 403 en el publicado?

Comment: Así es, la ruta que devuelve el 403 funciona correctamente en el Localhost (estoy utilizando Url.Action)

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar detalles de la función en el controlador que maneja esa solicitud POST /Clientes/Crear?

Comment: @RigobertoRamirezCruz agregué el código del Controlador. (El Controlador esta afectado por los filtros arriba citados)